# Using junction table or single table for dating app matches

Tags: sql, database, aws-amplify

[Schema design diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRq6s.png)

I am trying to design a database schema for a dating app such as tinder. I am using AWS Amplify Datastore as the backend. I am unsure whether I should use a junction table or a single table. I have two approaches I'm thinking of. Take a look at the pic to get a better idea of what I'm describing. If neither of my approaches are efficient, I'm open to new approaches. Also, here is list of queries I need to perform.

1. Get all the **matches** the user is in
2. Get all the **users** in a match with a specific user

Design 1 (single table)
Have a single table that stores the matches. Create a GSI on **user1_id** and **user2_id**. To get all the matches a user is in perform a query on both GSI's because a user can either be **user_1** or **user_2**. This way I can get also get a list of all the other users a specific user is in a match with and the **status**.

Design 2 (junction table)
Create GSI on **user_id** on junction table called **USERSMATCHES**. Query on the junction table's GSI and get the list of all the **matches_id** that the user is associate with. Then query all the **matches_id** from the matches table to get the **status**. To get all the users a specific user is in a match with, get a list of **matches_id** then query **USERSMATCHES** for each of the **matches_id** to get the **user_id**.

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Comment: Stackoverflow allows image uploading and it automatically created a link out of it.

Comment: Hi - not sure what your response has to do with my comment? Having all the information necessary to understand your question visible in one place makes it much easier for people to help you. The fact that this site allows you to upload images doesn’t mean it’s good practice (in most circumstances) and if you provide the information as requested you are more likely to get help